# SQL select the all ID's above average

Tags: sql, select, average, h2

I have a table called flights with the columns:

```
DEP_DELAY, ID
```

I want to select all IDs which are above the average of DEP_DELAY and count these ID's together, to know how many ID's are above average DEP_DELAY.

I tried this one:

```
select avg(DEP_DELAY), count(ID)
from flights
group by DEP_DELAY
having DEP_DELAY > (select avg(DEP_DELAY) from flights)
```

But this one won't work, I would be really grateful for any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You want the `having` clause as a `where` clause.  And no `group by` in the outer query because you want only one row:

```
select avg(f.DEP_DELAY), count(*)
from flights f
where f.DEP_DELAY > (select avg(f2.DEP_DELAY) from flights f2);
```

Comment: is this the only possible way of doing it?

Comment: @ideasia . . . No.  SQL often has lots of ways of expressing logic.  This is a very reasonable approach.  Window functions are also a very reasonable approach.